# How to separate string and add up to row of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to use regex and pandas function but I could not this df make to like below table
How can i make to this?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['COD21C0521/534/583/584','COD21C0540_1/587_1/588_1']},index=['AAA','BBB'])
```

|  | a |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | COD21C0521 |
| AAA | COD21C0534 |
| AAA | COD21C0583 |
| AAA | COD21C0584 |
| BBB | COD21C0540_1 |
| BBB | COD21C0587_1 |
| BBB | COD21C0588_1 |

Comment: yep , i missed i will fix that

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `str[:]` (indexing), `str.split` and `explode` methods:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a':['COD21C0521/534/583/584','COD21C0540_1/587_1/588_1']},
     index=['AAA','BBB']) 

s = df['a'].str[:7] + df['a'].str[7:].str.split('/').explode()
print(s)
```

yields

```
AAA      COD21C0521
AAA      COD21C0534
AAA      COD21C0583
AAA      COD21C0584
BBB    COD21C0540_1
BBB    COD21C0587_1
BBB    COD21C0588_1
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Be aware that you can't assign the result back to the dataframe (`df['a'] = ...`), since there are only two rows in the original dataframe, and seven in the output. Hence `s` for Series.